# Не идет запуск ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu

Создал виртуалку убунту сервера 22.04.3, чтобы накатить на него спарк для лабораторной. Всё это сделал, во время установки перезагружал несколько раз сервер и всё работало, но сейчас перезапустил и ничего не работает, точнее работает но я не знаю, то с этим делать:
[image: картинка запуска]
Устанавливал по [гайду](https://ru.linux-console.net/?p=2867)

Я пытался горячими клавишами открыть консоль, перезапускать виртуалку но ничего не менялось.

Comment: Пробовали ждать?

Comment: @andreymal, жду ещё до того как вопрос написал и продолжаю ждать, но ничего не проиходит

Comment: Если «OpenBSD Secure Shell server» таки запустился, то попробуйте подключиться через ssh ([пробросив порт](https://teletype.in/@dobriydenis/virtualbox-port) из виртуалки или типа того)

Comment: а нажать `Alt-F2`? может tty2 работает... что-то припоминаю, что надо убирать `cloud-init` если не нужен

Comment: вангую место на диске кончилось)